# Creating AST from custom syntax in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I am building a small framework that reads my custom made HTML syntax and converts it into HTML code. However, I am stuck at tokenising my code and creating an AST. I understand that the algorithm requires recursive approach but I cannot figure out how to do it properly.

This is my custom code in `app.txt` file:

```
View {
    Heading {
        
    }

    Text {

    }
}
```

And here is my recursive parser so far:

```
function parse(source) {
    let tag = "";
    let children = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        const char = source[i];

        if (char === "{") {
            const child = parse(source.substring(i + 1, source.length));
            children.push(child);
        } else if (char === "}") {
            return {
                tag: tag,
                children: children
            };
        } else {
            tag += char;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

The parses is expected to produce something like this (and should be able to go to any depth):

```
{
    tag: "View",
    children: [
        {
            tag: "Heading",
            children: []
        },
        {
            tag: "Text",
            children: []
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'll be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's write your grammar more or less formally:

```
tag := name '{' children '}'
name := letter | letter name
children := tag | tag children
letter := [a-z]
```

Then, let's write a parsing function for each rule in the grammar. We need two helper functions: `getsym`, which returns the first meaningful (non-whitespace) symbol from the input, and `nextsym`, which removes that symbol.

Working example:

```js
function parse(text) {
    let chars = [...text]

    function getsym() {
        while (chars.length > 0 && /\s/.test(chars[0]))
            chars.shift()
        return chars[0] || ''
    }

    function nextsym() {
        return chars.shift()
    }

    return tag()

    //

    function tag() {
        let n = name()

        if (getsym() !== '{')
            throw new SyntaxError()
        nextsym()

        let c = children(text)

        if (getsym() !== '}')
            throw new SyntaxError()
        nextsym()

        return {name: n, children: c}
    }

    function name() {
        let t = letter()
        if (t)
            return t + name()
        return ''
    }

    function letter() {
        if (/[a-z]/i.test(getsym()))
            return nextsym()
    }

    function children() {
        if (getsym() === '}')
            return []
        let t = tag()
        return [t, ...children()]
    }

}

///

text = ` View {
    Heading {
        Content {
            One {}
            Two {}
            Three {}
        }
    }
    Text {
        More {}
    }
}
`

console.log(parse(text))
```

That being said, if you plan for a more complex grammar, a more practical option would be to use a parser generator like peg.js.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: what are other software packages with same purpose as peg.js? Just want to know what other options there are . . .

Comment: Where I can read more basic knowledge about parsing algorithms and methodology?

Comment: I found the [nearley grammer](https://nearley.js.org/docs/grammar) and [chevrotain](https://chevrotain.io/docs/)